# static resources is implemented , but page is not working in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, jquery

im using static resources name j-qurey
i can attached jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.zip

den my jquery visualforce code using

my code :

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">

        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.j_query, '/js/jquery_latest.js')}"></script>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.j_query, '/js/jquery-ui-git.js')}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jq$= jQuery.noConflict();
            jq$(document).ready(function()
            {
                 jq$("#ton").click(function(){
                    jq$("p").remove(".italic");
                  });
            });
        </script>

<body>

<p>This is a paragraph in the div.</p>
<p class="italic"><i>This is another paragraph in the div.</i></p>
<p class="italic"><i>This is another paragraph in the div.</i></p>
<button id="ton">Remove all p elements with class="italic"</button>

</body>
</apex:page>
```

but its not working ,
anyone can help to me....

what ill do

Regards,
s.ganesh

Comment: could you share your code

Comment: question is a little vague, there are different ways to reference the static resource depending on how you are using it and the type of file ... (zip or raw file). How are you referencing the file.

Comment: likely a duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13965/using-jquery-remove-empty-methods-are-not-working-in-visualforce

Answer (score 3):

The right way to use static resource at the visualforce page is use of `apex:includeScript` tag:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.j_query, '/js/jquery-ui-git.js')}" />
```

You may want to learn more about it here: [Using Static Resources](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm)

In your example i can see, that you want to remove a classname. But use of `remove()` function is wrong. You need the `removeClass()` instead. And when referencing a class name you dont need to add a comma to it:

```
jq$("p").removeClass("italic");
```

Comment: but its working